# display property when doing show/hide

Tags: jquery, css, media, show

I am working on a design with media queries here. In the larger design, I have a few items that are hidden by `hide();`.

But in the smaller design, I want them to stay shown. So I used a `display:block !important` value.

Well now the content in the larger version is set to display. Oh the confusion!

Style:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 180px) {
    .backCat{display:block !important;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .backCat{display:none;}  // no clue what to put here
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="releases">
    <h3>Releases</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h4>Strangers on a Plain</h4>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/160x160">
            <p><b>Released:</b>August 2011</p>
        </li>
        <li class="backCat"><h4>Nagano Car Rental</h4><img src="100x100.gif">
            <p><b>Released:</b>August 2010</p>
        </li>

        <li class="backCat"><h4>Panic Box</h4><img src="100x100.gif">
            <p><b>Released:</b>May 2009</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" style="float:left; margin-bottom:10px;" class="moreReleases">More Releases</a> 
</div> <!-- end releases -->
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.backCat').hide();
    $('.moreReleases').click(function(){
        $('.backCat').show(500);
        $('.moreReleases').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to use the hide() call to hide them in the larger view? If you remove the display: block line in your small design, the display: none style in your larger view will be applied and you won't need the explicit hide() call?

Comment: have you tried putting a max-width on your first .backcat to prevent overlap? @media only screen and (min-width: 180px) and (max-width: 767px)

Comment: hi everyone just a quick apology i didn't see the responses until now. i am sure the answer is in here somewhere! will get back soon with a checkmark :)

Answer (score 0):

the `!important` declaration is taking precedence since the `min-width` condition in your first media query remains true when your second is satisfied. Change your first media query to `@media only screen and (min-width: 180px) and (max-width: 767px)`. You might also get away with simply placing `important` behind your `display: none;` declaration as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set a max-width for the smaller screen version since 768 is at least 180

Answer (score 0):

Ok, tested the idea I suggested above and it works:

```
<style>
@media only screen and (min-width: 180px) {
    .moreReleases{ display: none; }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .backCat{display:none;}
    a.moreReleases{display: inline;}
}    
</style>

<div id="releases">
    <h3>Releases</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h4>Strangers on a Plain</h4>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/160x160">
            <p><b>Released:</b>August 2011</p>
        </li>
        <li class="backCat"><h4>Nagano Car Rental</h4><img src="100x100.gif">
            <p><b>Released:</b>August 2010</p>
        </li>

        <li class="backCat"><h4>Panic Box</h4><img src="100x100.gif">
            <p><b>Released:</b>May 2009</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" style="float:left; margin-bottom:10px;" class="moreReleases">More Releases</a> 
</div> <!-- end releases -->
<script language="javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.moreReleases').click(function(){
        $('.backCat').show(500);
        $('.moreReleases').hide();
    });
});

</script>
```

On the small layout we don't do anything, just let the links display (and hide the more releases link since it's unneeded). On the larger display we hide the blocks by default and show the moreReleases link. Clicking the link does what it did before, showing the blocks and hiding the link.

Answer (score 0):

.hide() is "browser-size agnostic" and will run regardless of what your browser size is and that's why .backCat is being removed on the smaller screen. You want to remove this from the js.

Once you have that gone, you'll need to remove !important so it reads:

`@media only screen and (min-width: 180px) {
.backCat{display:block;} 
}`

Now .backCat will display on smaller screens but gets turned off in the bigger screen. What's left is you'll have to add stying for .moreReleases so that it shows (using display:block or something) when .backCat is hidden, and hides (i.e. display:none) when .backCat is shown.

Hope this helps!